# State resets on published site, works fine on localhost

Tags: reactjs, react-native, semantic-ui

I have this searchbar function that searches the wines in State to narrow them down. When you type, State changes to "isLoading === true" and displays the proper result for a second, but then goes back to displaying all the results and not just the parameters entered. My website it up https://www.winewise.biz/allwines so you can test it out. Here's the code for the searchbar:

```
import _ from "lodash";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Search} from "semantic-ui-react";
import API from '../../utils/API'
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"
import "./searchwines.css";


export default class SearchBar extends Component {

    state = {
        wines: []
    }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.resetComponent();
  }

  resetComponent = () =>
    this.setState({ isLoading: false, wines: [], value: "" });

    //What shows on the results bar when you click on it:
  handleResultSelect = (e, { result }) =>
    this.setState({ value: result.Wine });

  handleSearchChange = (e, { value }) => {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true, value });
    API.getWines()
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ wines: res.data }) 
      }
      )
      .catch(err => console.log(err));

    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.state.value.length < 1) return this.resetComponent();

      const re = new RegExp(_.escapeRegExp(this.state.value), "i");
      //what is being tested for in search input
      const isMatch = result => re.test(result.Wine);

      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        wines: _.filter(this.state.wines, isMatch)
      });
    }, 300);
  };

  render() {

    const { isLoading, value, wines } = this.state;

    const resRender = ({ Wine, Producer, _id }) => (
      <Link to={"/details/" + _id}>
        <div key="name">
        {Wine}, {Producer}
        </div>
      </Link>
    );


    return (

          <Search 
            placeholder="Search wines..."
            loading={isLoading}
            onResultSelect={this.handleResultSelect}
            onSearchChange={_.debounce(this.handleSearchChange, 500, {
              leading: true
            })}
            results={wines}
            value={value}
            resultRenderer={resRender}
          />

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Put the initial state in the constructor

Comment: ComponentWillMount is deprecated and should not be used btw

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks to me like you have 2 conditions racing to set the state.

You kick off an API request during the `handleSearchChange`, which sets the state. Some of those API requests which are happening with every type of the keyboard are setting the state *after* you have filtered. It probably works fine on localhost because the request makes it back before the filter is applied (< 300ms) as you have the setTimeout.

You should use promises to control the flow and filter only after the api request. I'd also recommend since it doesn't look like you are doing any filtering server side, that you make that API request only once, and then just filter in the component state.

Watch the network tab and you can see how when your API calls succeed, the state gets set to the full list of unfiltered results.

Some small changes that should help, minus the fact that you shouldn't call `API.getWines()` on every type.

```
handleSearchChange = (e, { value }) => {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true, value });
    API.getWines()
      .then(res => {
      const re = new RegExp(_.escapeRegExp(this.state.value), "i");
      //what is being tested for in search input
      const isMatch = result => re.test(result.Wine);
        this.setState({ 
          wines: _.filter(this.state.wines, isMatch)        
        }) 
      }
      )
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. So, everyone's suggestions were very insightful and I realize it seems intuitive to put everything into state initially and then filter, but the problem is when someone makes a mistake typing and tries to delete, some of the wines may be removed from state.

What I did was just set up another variable in state called "list" that tracks the filtered wines from state. This works great!

```
import _ from "lodash";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Search} from "semantic-ui-react";
import API from '../../utils/API'
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"
import "./searchwines.css";


export default class SearchBar extends Component {

    state = {
        wines: [],
        list: []
    }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.resetComponent();
    API.getWines()
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ wines: res.data }) 
      }
      )
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  resetComponent = () =>
    this.setState({ isLoading: false, wines: [], value: "" });

    //What shows on the results bar when you click on it:
  handleResultSelect = (e, { result }) =>
    this.setState({ value: result.Wine });

  handleSearchChange = (e, { value }) => {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true, value });
    API.getWines()
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ wines: res.data }) 
      }
      )
      .catch(err => console.log(err));

  setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.state.value.length < 1) return this.resetComponent();

      const re = new RegExp(_.escapeRegExp(this.state.value), "i");
      //what is being tested for in search input
      const isMatch = result => re.test(result.Wine);

      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        list: _.filter(this.state.wines, isMatch)
      });
    }, 300);
  };


  render() {

    const { isLoading, value, wines, list } = this.state;

    const resRender = ({ Wine, Producer, _id }) => (
      <Link to={"/details/" + _id}>
        <div key="name">
        {Wine}, {Producer}
        </div>
      </Link>
    );


    return (

          <Search 
            placeholder="Search wines..."
            loading={isLoading}
            onResultSelect={this.handleResultSelect}
            onSearchChange={_.debounce(this.handleSearchChange, 500, {
              leading: true
            })}
            results={list}
            value={value}
            resultRenderer={resRender}
          />

    );
  }
}
```